# Quick sorting is not working

Tags: java, quicksort

I don't have any compilation errors but it still not working. I think it's something about the array bounds but I'm not able to fix it. I tried to change them but still not working.

here is my code:

```
public class QuickSort {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] A = new int[] {6,2,7,8,1};

    quickSort(A,0,A.length-1);
    printArray(A);
}

public static void quickSort(int[] A,int P,int r){
    int Q = partition(A,P,r);
    if (P < Q-1){
        quickSort(A,P,Q-1);
    }

    if (Q < r){
        quickSort(A,Q,r);
    }

}

public static int partition(int[] A,int P, int r){
    int i = P;  //left
    int j = r;  //right
    int pivot = A[(P+r)/2];
    int temp;

    while (i <= j){  

        while (pivot > A[i]){
        i++;
        }

        while (pivot < A[j]){
            j--;
        }

        if (i <= j){
            temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return j;
}
public static void printArray(int[] A){
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length;i++){
        System.out.println(A[i]);
    }
}
}
```

The parameter P will be the start and r is the end. I'm picking the pivot from the middle

Comment: this question can be considered as seeking help for debugging.

Comment: I wrote this program with the help of few videos on youtube but it's not running and I'm not able to fix it.

Comment: *...but it still not working...* -- How is it not working? What input are you giving it?  What is the expected vs actual output?  An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is much more helpful than expecting people to put together test cases themselves when asking for debugging help.

Comment: it's not working at all (sorry for my bad English). the program should sort an array of integers from the smallest to the largest. this was my input  int[] A = new int[] {6,2,7,8,1};

Comment: What have you discovered while running though a debugger? Do you have an idea where the problem is?

Comment: I guess it's the array bounds when I try to run it I get this massege Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at quicksort.QuickSort.partition(QuickSort.java:44)
 at quicksort.QuickSort.quickSort(QuickSort.java:25)
 at quicksort.QuickSort.quickSort(QuickSort.java:31)
 at quicksort.QuickSort.quickSort(QuickSort.java:31)
 at quicksort.QuickSort.quickSort(QuickSort.java:27)
 at quicksort.QuickSort.main(QuickSort.java:20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your naming was very unintuitive. Sticking to naming conventions makes your code easier to understand for others.
2. in partition return i instead of j.
3. When using recursion one must ensure it ends. You keep on processing your array with nonsense bounds in case (r-P<2)!
   insert a return statement like this into your quicksort method

Code:

```
public static void quickSort(int[] A,int l,int r) {
    if ((r-l)<2) return; //end recursion when there is just one or less elements to sort 

    int p = partition(A,l,r);

    if (l < p-1) { quickSort(A,l,p-1); }

    if (p < r) { quickSort(A,p,r); } 
}
```